# Minimizing overfitting when doing hyperparameter Tuning

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, hyperparameter-tuning, grid-search

Generaly when using Sklearn's GridSearchCV (or RandomizedGridSearchCV), we get best model with best test score even if the model overfits a little bit. How can we compute generalization error efficiently and force GridSearchCV to get best model with minimum generalization error?